# How to display related data from dataset in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, dataset, master-detail

I've got a dataset with two tables, a simple one to many parent child relationship going on. eg;

```
Parent Table
ParentId (int)
Name     (string)

Child Table
ChildId (int)
ParentId (int)
Name     (string)
```

In this dataset I've got a relationship (ParentChildRelation) set up between the parent and child on the parent id field. And if I programtically do a Parent.getChildRows() call I see the correct related child records so I know the relationship is good.

I need to display a datagrid with a list of the parent rows and have another separate datagrid displaying the list of child records for the selected parent.

So far on my window in code behind I have

```
private DataSet _parentChildDataSet;
public DataSet ParentChildDataSet
{
    get
    {
        return _parentChildDataSet;
    }
    set 
    {
        _parentChildDataSet = value;
    }


    public DataView ParentView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ParentChildDataSet.Tables["Parent"].DefaultView;
        }
    }

    public DataRelation ParentChildRelation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ParentChildDataSet.Relations["Parent_Child"] ;
        }
    }
```

I also set the datacontext for the window to itself in the windows constructor eg ;

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

and in my xaml

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentView}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1">
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentChildRelation}" Name="dataGrid2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

However I cannot get any child records to show up in dataGrid2.

I'm binding this grid to the datarelation name is this correct?

if I bind to another property on my window ;

```
    public DataView ChildrenView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ParentChildDataSet.Tables["Child"].DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

then I see all the records regardless of the parent as you would expect.

Thanks for any pointers anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return a DataView it is working but displays all.

Here you are returning a DataRelation

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentChildRelation}"
```

You need to return a DataView

Use the relation to produce the DataView

DataRowView.CreateChildView Method (DataRelation)

Comment: not sure why it was downvoted or by who, thanks for the information but is there no way to bind directly to the child view via xaml rather than call the CreateChildView method?

Comment: I ended up using a slightly different approach, I used another grid in the rowdetailstemplate of the master grid to display the child records. When the loadingrowdetails event fired I populated the itemssources of the child grid via a call to the parent datarows GetChildRows method. Thanks for the information

Comment: "You need to return a DataView use the relation to produce the DataView" was not the answer because you used a slightly different approach?

Comment: paparazzo, can you show some code example?  a Xaml code example? Otherwise I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this answer is hard to comprehend.