# How to render wpf master-detail datagrids from relational dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

This is a crosspost from [How to display related data from dataset in wpf datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126602/how-to-display-related-data-from-dataset-in-wpf-datagrid/42566345?noredirect=1), where I was unable to apply the suggested answer successfully.

My situation is identical to the one described in the source: I have 2 datatables (1 with invoices, 1 with the rows specifying what is being invoiced) in a dataset which share a relation, I further want to show those datatables in two datagrids as a master-detail view.

I have looked into the CreateChildView method, but I'm missing a key point somewhere. My current code for getting the childview:

```
public DataView ChildView {
    get {
        return ParentChildRelation.ParentTable.DefaultView[0].CreateChildView("orders")
    }
}
```

The problem is two-fold, firstly I obviously have the index fixed, meaning I always get the childview of the first row of the parenttable. Secondly, I am failing miserably in fetching a new child view when a new row is selected in the parent view (ChildView only gets called on initialization).

My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentView}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Name="dataGrid1" 
    />

    <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildView}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Name="dataGrid2"
    />
</Grid>
```

I'd like to make this a XAML solution and avoid writing eventhandlers updating the childview. I've tried playing around with DataContext but got nowhere, documentation on how to utilze this structure with datasets and relations is really slim (makes me wonder if I'm going down the right path).

I'm missing the semantics how the detail view is supposed to know which parent was selected and which items it should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `DataSet` for quite some time, but for such master-detail scenarios you can try

```
 <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ParentDataGrid, Converter={...}}"/>
```

You will get the `SelectedItem` which would be parent row, and then you can do something with this row and construct/get a `ICollection` to return from that `IValueConverter`.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Great solution which even let me trash a lot of support code for the table relations!